# using cmake as configuration tool while coding in QT Creator

Tags: qt, cmake, qmake

Currently I am using the command line compilation for my project and i used `cmake` to configure my project. so for my project i already have my `CMakeLists.txt` configured.

Now I'm planning to build project using the `QT Creator`. The problem is that I do not want to rewrite configuration settings again to use `qmake` so. Put differently, i am kind of trying to keep `cmake` as my default configuration tool. So is there any way i can still use my good old `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Creator should allow you to open a CMake project.  I haven't tried this, but see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.2/creator-project-cmake.html

Comment: The method specified here works for me only on OSX, when I open a CMakeLists.txt from Qt Creator in order to generate my project from Linux latest QtCreator(2.6), the program hangs when running  cmake